# C# Unity on update and mouse clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I have recently starting to learn unity, I have some problem that I don't understand, the value of `mouseClicked` is `false` as I set it at the beginning, but after click I wish to set it to `true`, and then the problem starts, it prints that the value of mouseClicked is true and false at the same time, how is it possible?

```
public class Button1 : MonoBehaviour
{       
    float movespeed = 0.5f;
    float menuspeed = 5f;       
    bool mousEn = false;
    bool mouseClicked = false;      
    GameObject iconNew;
    GameObject dropQuad;        
    GameObject Mtx2;

    void Start () 
    {
        iconNew = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("IconNew");
        dropQuad = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DropQuad1");           
        Mtx2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Mtxt2");        
    }       
    void Update ()
    {                   
        if (mousEn && transform.position.z>-0.3f)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.back * movespeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (!mousEn && transform.position.z<0f)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * movespeed * Time.deltaTime);  
        }           
        Debug.Log(mouseClicked); //both false and true          
        if (mouseClicked && Mtx2.transform.position.y>10f)
        {               
            Mtx2.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * menuspeed * Time.deltaTime);                
        }           
        else if (!mouseClicked && Mtx2.transform.position.y!=12f)
        {               
            Mtx2.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * menuspeed * Time.deltaTime);              
        }           
    }       
    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        renderer.material.color = Color.gray;
        mousEn = true;      
    }       
    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        renderer.material.color = Color.white;
        mousEn = false;         
    }       
    void OnMouseDown ()
    {
        mouseClicked = !mouseClicked;
    }
}
```

Comment: It can't be true and false at the same time. It can switch to true and then back to false the next time through, is that what you're seeing? Or you might be logging another `bool` somewhere and are getting confused about what log entry is what.

Comment: Put a debug log statement in OnMouseDown to see how many times that is firing. It might be that it's firing multiple times and alternating the boolean.

Comment: @user2025312 That's a good idea but `OnMouseDown` only fires once on first mouse down.  In fact as written `mouseClicked` will never change back from true.  Tim's comments seems likely.

Comment: You can use Inspector to debug your component. Select your component in runtime and switch it to debug mode — that way you'll be able to see all internal fields.